# Netbeans automatic code completion of variables

Tags: netbeans

I found an interesting Stackoverflow topic, but it is an old one and I'm afraid people won't be reacting anymore, so I hope it is ok to create a new one.

First of, I am using Netbeans 7.2 and I want to use automatic code completion more. It works nice on methods/classes with the '.' already, but I would like it for the variable names aswell.

So I found this topic: [How can I make auto completion in netbeans include both variables as well as methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362822/how-can-i-make-auto-completion-in-netbeans-include-both-variables-as-well-as-met) , more precisly the accepted answer.

This is what I have always wanted! Except one issue, it decides to automatically insert the name if only one result is available, while I am still typing unaware of that fact.

I have tried disabling Insert Single Proposals Automatically (Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion), and it does kind of work. But once I type the next letter, it still decides to complete it automatically.

Does anyone know a fix for this or another way to achieve the same?

Regards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, I found it now: If you want it as I described in the opening post, then set this for Completion Selectors in Java:

`[.,;:([+-=]` (Note the extra white space on the end, it **is** important.

Now it will not autocomplete on any character anymore, but still give you the suggestions box.

Comment: brilliant ! save the day.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **(Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completion)**

Select Language **Java** 
add tick to **Auto Popup on Typing Any Java Identifier Part**

and you can tick **Subword Completion**

Comment: Was this added recently? I'm asking this because I'm wondering if I missed that option when I asked this question or if it's new.

Comment: I also had problems with it . When i research i found this option and I wanted to share. I don't know this added recently or not.