# struts2 netbeans plugin intellisense for struts2 tags in jsp pages not working

Tags: jsp, struts2, autocomplete, intellisense, netbeans-7

![enter image description here][1]I have installed struts2 plugin in netbeans.
The struts2 tags are working fine but they are not autocompleted nor shown by netbeans intellisense (ctrl + space)
each time i have to write thestruts2 tags fully and their each and every attribute manually 
please help me out , i have a big project to complete within short time span.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-can-i-make-auto-completion-in-netbeans-include-both-variables-as-well-as-met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362822/how-can-i-make-auto-completion-in-netbeans-include-both-variables-as-well-as-met)

Comment: at the bottom-right of the netbeans window, do you see a red-mark showing any exception ?

Comment: i m getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Check your netbeans IDE whether these checkboxes are enabled. Go to tools->options->code completion and check the following image. Code completion works fine for me.

[image: netbeans auto competion code]

Which version of netbeans you are working in?

Comment: I m using netbeans 7.3.1 and i m not getting anything in my tools->option->code completion in language drop down box.it's blank

Comment: Are you getting any checkboxes like shown above in your code completion tab. There is nothing to do with language dropdown.

Comment: No that page is totally blank